# Updating dataframe updates entire column instead of the row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm importing a csv as a dataframe and then I'm updating a column in the dataframe and exporting it to a new csv file. However, the first update statement appears to be updating all rows for the entire column (instead of just for that row). I'm using `df.at` with the index as I iterate through the dataframe so I'm lost as to what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# import  spreadsheet data
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\Projects\\data\\data.csv', dtype=str)

df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

def write_file():
    for index, row in df.iterrows():

        type = str(df['Type'].values[0])

            if "test" in type:

                df.at[index, "A"] = "Update 1"

            if "test2" in department:
                df.at[index, 'B'] = "Update 2"


write_file()

df.to_csv('updated')
```

Comment: I suspect you can do this without the for loop and in about two lines of code.  Mind provding a sample input file explanation of the changes and expected output?

Comment: `type = str(df['Type'].values[0])` doesn't this mean `type` is unchanged throughout your loop?

Comment: going to guess your type should be something like df.at[index, "Type"]...but not familiar

Comment: I do need to update the "A" column though, but for some reason the entire column gets updated for every row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type = str(df['Type'].values[0])` doesn't this mean type is unchanged throughout your loop? Therefore, all `A` and `B` columns are updated to the same value. I believe you want

```
type = str(row['Type'])
```

On the other hand, you can make do without looping:

```
def write_file():
    df.loc[df['Type'].astype(str).str.contains('test'), 'A'] = 'Update 1'
```